# Docker compose getting connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3333 with AdonisJS, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, adonis.js

i am trying to setup an application with docker/adonis/postgres/mongo,
but I am getting an ECONNREFUSED error

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3333

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]

RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli && npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "ace", "serve"]
```

dockercompose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
      
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_PASSWORD: 1234
      MONGO_USER: MONGO
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message mentions port 3333. But nowhere in your docker-compose file is a port 3333 exposed to the Host.

Where do you try to connect from?

- If from app container, then services like 'db' and 'mongo' are not on localhost. Looking from inside 'app' service, the db service is at db:5432 and the mongo service is at mongo:27017.
- If from the host, then db is on localhost:5432 and mongo is at localhost:27017.

Is becomes more clear is you use other ports on the host than internally.